# What file and line number is pcap_findalldevs() defined in?

Tags: libpcap

What file and line number is pcap_findalldevs() defined in?. I am looking in the libpcap source for the place where pcap_findalldevs() is defined. I found the prototype in pcap.h but where is the complete functionality defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see:

```
# git clone git://git.debian.org/git/users/rfrancoise/libpcap.git
Cloning into libpcap...
[snap]
# grep -ri pcap_findalldevs libpcap |grep '{'
libpcap/fad-sita.c:int pcap_findalldevs(pcap_if_t **alldevsp, char *errbuf) {
```

Seems my lucky day !

Here complete source code of this function:

```
int pcap_findalldevs(pcap_if_t **alldevsp, char *errbuf) {
        *alldevsp = 0;
        strcpy(errbuf, "");
        if (acn_parse_hosts_file(errbuf))
                {
                return -1;
                }
        if (acn_findalldevs(errbuf))
                {
                return -1;
                }
        *alldevsp = acn_if_list;
        acn_if_list = 0;    

        return 0;
}
```

Then, the answer of your question is: **fad-sita.c** !

Answer (score 0):

It's defined in several places, because the way it's done depends on the OS on which you're running.  On Windows with WinPcap, it's defined in `fad-win32.c`; on UN*Xes that have `getifaddrs()`, it's defined in `fad-getad.c`; on Solaris 8 or later, it's defined in `fad-glifc.c`; on other UN*Xes that support packet capture on local interfaces, it's defined in `fad-gifc.c`; on UN*Xes that don't support packet capture at all, it's defined (to return no interfaces) in `fad-null.c`; and, if whoever configured and built libpcap happened to configure in support for capturing from remote devices provided by [SITA](http://www.sita.aero/), it's defined in `fad-sita.c`.

(Yes, the other answer is wrong; they should not have assumed that those of us who write code in libpcap all like putting the opening curly brace of a function on the same line as the name of the function - I don't, and won't, do that.)